# How to make different instances of consumers in the same consumer group consume different shards of the same kinesis stream?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I'm following the example given in [spring-cloud-stream-samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kinesis-samples/kinesis-produce-consume) with the following modifications.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      instanceCount: 2
      bindings:
        produceOrder-out-0:
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            partitionCount: 2
            partitionSelectorName: eventPartitionSelectorStrategy
            partitionKeyExtractorName: eventPartitionKeyExtractorStrategy
        processOrder-in-0:
          group: eventConsumers
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
    function:
      definition: processOrder;produceOrder
```

**ProducerConfiguration.java**

```
package demo.config;

import demo.stream.Event;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PartitionSelectorStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerConfiguration.class);
    @Bean
    public PartitionSelectorStrategy eventPartitionSelectorStrategy() {
        return new PartitionSelectorStrategy() {
            @Override
            public int selectPartition(Object key, int partitionCount) {
                if(key instanceof Integer) {
                    int partition = (((Integer)key)%partitionCount + partitionCount)%partitionCount;
                    logger.info("key {} falls into partition {}" , key , partition);
                    return partition;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy eventPartitionKeyExtractorStrategy() {
        return new PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy() {
            @Override
            public Object extractKey(Message<?> message) {
                if(message.getPayload() instanceof Event) {
                    return ((Event) message.getPayload()).hashCode();
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I run two instances of this application by setting `--spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=0` and `--spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=1` I'm able to see the events getting produced. However, only one of the instance is consuming the records from both the partitions, the other instance is not consuming despite the producer creating partitioned records.

Logs seen in KinesisProducer

```
2022-09-04 00:17:22.628  INFO 34029 --- [           main] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=LATEST, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='test_stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}], consumerGroup='eventConsumers'}
2022-09-04 00:17:22.658  INFO 34029 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 64398 (http) with context path ''
2022-09-04 00:17:22.723  INFO 34029 --- [           main] demo.KinesisApplication                  : Started KinesisApplication in 18.487 seconds (JVM running for 19.192)
2022-09-04 00:17:23.938  INFO 34029 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=LATEST, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='test_stream', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=NEW}] has been started.
2022-09-04 00:17:55.222  INFO 34029 --- [io-64398-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-09-04 00:17:55.222  INFO 34029 --- [io-64398-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-09-04 00:17:55.224  INFO 34029 --- [io-64398-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-09-04 00:17:55.598  INFO 34029 --- [io-64398-exec-1] demo.stream.OrdersSource                 : Event sent: Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=5fbaca2f-d947-423d-a1f1-b1c9c268d2d0, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
2022-09-04 00:17:56.337  INFO 34029 --- [ask-scheduler-3] demo.config.ProducerConfiguration        : key 1397835167 falls into partition 1
2022-09-04 00:18:02.047  INFO 34029 --- [io-64398-exec-2] demo.stream.OrdersSource                 : Event sent: Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=83021259-89b5-4451-a0ec-da3152d37a58, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
2022-09-04 00:18:02.361  INFO 34029 --- [ask-scheduler-3] demo.config.ProducerConfiguration        : key 147530256 falls into partition 0
```

Logs seen in KinesisConsumer

```
2022-09-04 00:17:28.050  INFO 34058 --- [           main] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter{shardOffsets=[KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=LATEST, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='test_stream', shard='shardId-000000000001', reset=false}], consumerGroup='eventConsumers'}
2022-09-04 00:17:28.076  INFO 34058 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 64399 (http) with context path ''
2022-09-04 00:17:28.116  INFO 34058 --- [           main] demo.KinesisApplication                  : Started KinesisApplication in 18.566 seconds (JVM running for 19.839)
2022-09-04 00:17:29.365  INFO 34058 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : The [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, sequenceNumber='49632927200161141377996226513172299243826807332967284754', timestamp=null, stream='test_stream', shard='shardId-000000000001', reset=false}, state=NEW}] has been started.
2022-09-04 00:17:57.346  INFO 34058 --- [esis-consumer-1] demo.stream.OrderStreamConfiguration     : An order has been placed from this service Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=5fbaca2f-d947-423d-a1f1-b1c9c268d2d0, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
2022-09-04 00:18:04.384  INFO 34058 --- [esis-consumer-1] demo.stream.OrderStreamConfiguration     : An order has been placed from this service Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=83021259-89b5-4451-a0ec-da3152d37a58, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
```

spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis version : 2.2.0

I have these following questions:

1. For [Static shard distribution within a single consumer group](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#static-shard-distribution-within-a-single-consumer-group), is there any other parameter that needs to be configured that I have missed?
2. Do I need to specify the DynamoDB Checkpoint properties only for dynamic shard distribution?

**EDIT**

I have added the DEBUG logs seen in KinesisProducer below:

```
2022-09-07 08:30:38.120  INFO 4993 --- [io-64398-exec-1] demo.stream.OrdersSource                 : Event sent: Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=b3927132-a80d-481e-a219-dbd0c0c7d124, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
2022-09-07 08:30:38.806  INFO 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-3] demo.config.ProducerConfiguration        : key 1842629003 falls into partition 1
2022-09-07 08:30:38.812 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'produceOrder-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=1, id=9cb8ec58-4a9e-7b6f-4263-c9d4d1eec906, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519638809}]
2022-09-07 08:30:38.813 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-3] tractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler : org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler@63811d15 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=1, scst_partitionOverride=0, id=731f444b-d3df-a51a-33de-8adf78e1e746, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519638813}]
2022-09-07 08:30:38.832 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'produceOrder-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=1, scst_partitionOverride=0, id=731f444b-d3df-a51a-33de-8adf78e1e746, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519638813}]
2022-09-07 08:35:51.153  INFO 4993 --- [io-64398-exec-2] demo.stream.OrdersSource                 : Event sent: Event [id=null, subject=Order [id=6a5b3084-11dc-4080-a80e-61cc73315139, name=pen], type=ORDER, originator=KinesisProducer]
2022-09-07 08:35:51.915  INFO 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-5] demo.config.ProducerConfiguration        : key 1525662264 falls into partition 0
2022-09-07 08:35:51.916 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'produceOrder-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=0, id=115c5421-00f2-286d-de02-0020e9322a17, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519951916}]
2022-09-07 08:35:51.916 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-5] tractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler : org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler@63811d15 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=0, scst_partitionOverride=0, id=145be7e8-381f-af73-e430-9cb645ff785f, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519951916}]
2022-09-07 08:35:51.917 DEBUG 4993 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'produceOrder-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[126], headers={scst_partition=0, scst_partitionOverride=0, id=145be7e8-381f-af73-e430-9cb645ff785f, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1662519951916}]
```

Comment: According to your logs you have only one shard in your `KinesisConsumer` application. I see that you consume over there both records, so perhaps those `0` & `1` partition keys are both landed in the same shard. I guess you must confirm first of all that your data is really distributed between shards...

Comment: I have updated my post to include DEBUG logs. I see that the message headers have `scst_partition=1` and `scst_partition=0` which are matching with the partition selected by the bean `eventPartitionSelectorStrategy`. Is the partition selected not the same as kinesis's shard? If so, how do I force records to be produced into a specific kinesis shard?

Comment: The partition is a key to take a cash to place with the same key to the same shard, but it it is indeed not a shard Id. Please, learn Kinesis more and I’d not surprised if both your records will be found in the shard…

Comment: Okay, I understand that we have no control over the shard by specifying the partition key. But Kinesis has the optional argument `ExplicitHashKey` for `PutRecord`. Is there any support for setting this value using spring-cloud-stream ?

Comment: No, it is not exposed at the moment, but you can produce a `PutRecordRequest` with that configuration instead of plain data and trying to rely on those partition strategies.